# What is best way to write api in rails with authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I want write api for my rails application and with authentication. I want to pass my associations data also but in selective and conditional manner.

If I use `respond_to` block for that then there will be a lot of mess in my controller that i do not want any ways.

What is best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This question is not very clear.  I don't really understand what you want to do, nor how "a lot of mess" will occur, or what you mean by "authentication".

Comment: I want write a `json` api in my rails app. "a lot of mess " means by scaffold i get a way to return `json` from controller but i that is for object with all its attributes and i don't want that. Instead i want few attributes of a object and few attributes from its association. So if do all this in my controller and respond_to block then my controller will messy. I hope now its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these gems `jbuilder` `rabl` `rails-api`. 
You can see free railscasts for

- [Jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder)
- [rabl](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl)
- [rails-api](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem)

Some other very good railscasts related to api

- [REST API Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning)
- [Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at grape. It is a REST-like API micro-framework for Ruby, and it has a related gem grape-entity which  defines the attributes to expose. They should be what you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of your application is only API then you can go with [RAIL_API Gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)
and your can configure you JSON reponse using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)